# Error when setting a FrameLayout's background on Android 4

Tags: java, android

Here this the code that I'm using:

```
progressFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.progressFrame);
progressFrame.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.startprogress);
```

All works fine on Android 2.3.3, but on Android 4 it crashes when trying to run the 'setBackgroundResource' line. Here is the logcat message:

```
07-06 17:31:28.159: W/dalvikvm(11848): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40be81f8)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bosi.sweetsmell/com.bosi.sweetsmell.activity.RubActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at com.bosi.sweetsmell.activity.RubActivity.onCreate(RubActivity.java:35)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
07-06 17:31:28.167: E/AndroidRuntime(11848):    ... 11 more
```

Here's hoping someone can help!

Comment: I think the problem is not with FrameLayout's background..you have a exception in a thread..that stop some initialization for FrameLayout.

Comment: But when I take out the second line, the app works fine.

Comment: what is line `RubActivity.java:35` ?

Comment: progressFrame.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.startprogress);

Comment: Then `progressFrame` is null. Perhaps you have a qualified layout somewhere that you've left this particular FrameLayout and/or its ID out of?

Comment: It's strange though, progressFrame is not null when running on Android 2.3.3, instead it runs absolutely fine. How can the same code fail in Android 4?

Comment: What is the name of your layout? Do you have multiple qualified layout folders (e.g. layout-land, layout-hdpi, layout-xhdpi)? If there is more than one place that you have this particular layout defined, then it's possible that your 4.0 emulator is pulling from another layout folder, and in that folder you've failed to set the ID for your FrameLayout.

Comment: You, my friend, are a star. That worked a treat. Could you add as an answer so that I can give full credit?

Comment: Great! And sure, I've posted one below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you have multiple qualified layout folders (e.g. layout-land, layout-hdpi, layout-xhdpi). If you do, it's likely that your 4.0 emulator is pulling from a separate layout folder in which you may not have properly assigned the ID for your `FrameLayout`.